# Multiple images/thumbnails carousel/slider with middle image preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

Greetings geeks easy on the Negative voting, this is my first time on stackoverflow
and I'm new to web dev.

I'm trying to achieve the following Image slider/carousel (Check image below)
[Multiple thumbnails Carousel with middle thumbnail view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39M2s.png)

3 thumbnails on the slider and the middle thumbnail should be viewed.

This is the closest snippet I could find...
[Code Snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/kMyR)

Comment: Just use something like Owl  https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/center.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/webbist/pen/BEKMGe) + code

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    center: true,
    items:3,
    loop:true,
    margin:50,
    responsive:{
        600:{
            items:3
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.owl-stage {
  height: 400px;  
}

.owl-stage {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.owl-item {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  transform: scale(0.9, 1);
}
.owl-item.center  {
   transform: scale(1.2, 1.3);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
    <span>Some caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
    <span>Some caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
    <span>Some caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
    <span>Some caption</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
    <span>Some caption</span>
  </div>
</div>
```